# Spanish Letters in LaTeX

Tags: spanish

How to write [Spanish letter n](https://howtotypesymbols.com/n-with-tilde/) with a tilde in LaTeX?

Comment: Use `\~n` for that. If you are using utf-8 encoding with lualatex or xetex, you can also simply paste the character from a Unicode character map. There are other combinations that construct characters with diacriticals, and online references that list them.

Comment: @rallg You can simply type `ñ` in all versions of latex, so pdflatex not just lualatex or xelatex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I did not know that! Probably because the last time I used pdflatex was... before there was a place called Spain.

Comment: good catch Sam. I was sure that has been answered but couldn't find it. And welcome TeX.SE sir Abdaal Ahmed.

Answer (score 1):

Here there is a small example to use directly from your computer keyboard the `ñ` (for example).

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 


\begin{document}
El ñino
\end{document}
```

Comment: ;-) +1 pero es "el niño", not "el ñino" 

Comment: @Rmano . We leave it so El ñino ihihhihihi

Comment: you only need `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} ` for old latex releases (older than 2018)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok. Now I do the variation.